# Laravel multiple requests and SSL

Tags: laravel, ssl

having an issue with my app now I have setup SSL on it.

I do use URL::previous and Route::back() in a few places, however since applying an SSL cert to my site, these methods do not seem to play nice or get the correct url / route they used to.

Is this to do with the SSL having to make multiple requests?

Thanks!

Comment: do you get an error when you click on those url's ? if so, which one?